# Sending objects with mockito perform

Tags: java, junit

Hello I'm trying to test method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="addOwner", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOwnerDo(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "Owner") Owner owner, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "addOwner";
        }
        ownerService.add(owner);
        return "redirect:addOwner";
    }
```

so I wrote this unit test case:

```
@Test
    public void testAddOwnerPost() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(post("/addOwner")
                .param("firstName", "Adam")
                .param("lastName", "Kowalski")
                .requestAttr("pet", new Pet())
                .requestAttr("phone", new Phone())) 
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }
```

the problem is, that Owner entity contains fields that are type of Pet and Phone:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    private String lastName;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private Pet pet;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Phone phone;
```

So the object beeing send to controller while testing has values of Pet and Phone equal to null. And I would like to send object that has those fields set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do the following:

On your test class create two attributes :

```
private Pet pet = new Pet();
private Phone phone = new Phone();
```

Before your `public void testAddOwnerPost()` create a new method : `@Before
    public void setUp()`

And then set all of our attribute inside the setUp class.

If you don't care about the value of your phone and pet I suggest you to use `Mockito.anyString() // for a string value`

O